# How to change axis color on polar chart

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, radar-chart, multiple-axes

I'm not sure how my axes turned green, but I want them to be **black**.

Could you tell me what code to add to change my axes color to black and where to add the code?

I would like the axes to be solid black lines. Thanks for your help!

[image: Current Plot]

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as py

class Radar(object):

    def __init__(self, fig, titles, labels, rect=None):
        if rect is None:
            rect = [0.05, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95]

        self.n = len(titles)
        self.angles = [a if a <=360. else a - 360. for a in np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)]
        self.axes = [fig.add_axes(rect, projection="polar", label="axes%d" % i) 
                     for i in range(self.n)]

        self.ax = self.axes[0]
        self.ax.set_thetagrids(self.angles, labels=titles, fontsize=12, weight="bold", color="black")

        for ax in self.axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
            self.ax.yaxis.grid(False)

        for ax, angle, label in zip(self.axes, self.angles, labels):
            ax.set_rgrids(range(1, 7), labels=label, angle=angle, fontsize=12)
            ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(0, 6)  

    def plot(self, values, *args, **kw):
        angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[self.angles, self.angles[0]])
        values = np.r_[values, values[0]]
        self.ax.plot(angle, values, *args, **kw)

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

titles = [
"Canada", "Australia", "New Zealand", "Japan", "China", "USA", "Mexico", "Finland", "Doha" 
]

labels = [
list("abcde"), list("12345"), list("uvwxy"), 
[" ", " ", "$156", "$158", "$160"],
list("jklmn"), list("asdfg"), list("qwert"), [" ", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5", "4.6"], list("abcde")
]

radar = Radar(fig, titles, labels)
radar.plot([1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2],  "--", lw=1, color="b", alpha=.5, label="USA 2014")
radar.plot([2.3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2],"-", lw=1, color="r", alpha=.5, label="2014")
radar.plot([3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2], "-", lw=1, color="g", alpha=.5, label="2013")
radar.plot([4.5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], "-", lw=1, color="y", alpha=.5, label="2012")

radar.ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.10),
      fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)

fig = py.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(6, 10, forward=True)
fig.savefig('test2png.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=1)
```

Comment: the code in your question produces dotted black lines for me, not solid green ones. Perhaps you have something set in your `matplotlibrc` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this with `ax.xaxis.grid()`. Just put the following line after you `set_ylim(0, 6)`:

```
ax.xaxis.grid(True,color='k',linestyle='-')
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know this stuff, @tom ? I'd like to learn what code to add to change things and where to add it. Right now I'm pretty much just guessing and checking. Once again, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just keep trying stuff. I started out just like that! It really is a case of the more you do, the more you pick up. The documentation is also a really good tool for finding hidden options